# Ionic Android build failed with an exception

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I got the following error in the implementation of the Ionic. How do I fix this error?

windows: 10
ionic: 2.2.3
cordova: 6.5.0

```
Morteza@DESKTOP-ORPCJPP MINGW64 /d/ionic/Morteza (master)
$ ionic run android

> ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:build D:\ionic\Morteza
> ionic-app-scripts build


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Morteza\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Subproject Path: CordovaLib


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.67 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It seems like a problem with your internet connection; are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: And the problem is not just the Internet do not have to download the packages and just run for my error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Into your android sdk find sdk manager.

open sdk manager with Run as administrator.

now download android sdk build tools matching version with your ionic

also download android api->sdk platform matching version with your ionic